# how to hide the tool bar in spotfire but keep the filtering options?

Tags: angular, spotfire, tibco, spotfire-webplayer

We want to hide the toolbar on top but allow users to show/hide the filter options. We tried to hide the menubar but it removes the filtering capability which we badly need. How can we achieve this?

We are embedding the visualization from spotfire to our angular app.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the spotfire API to embed pages into your app which would give the ability to create filters and such in your app.

But for a quick fix assuming you're just using an iframe.  Open in the web player and choose share and in the advance options you can choose which elements to hide when producing the URL /iframe to embed.

Use a text area with a button to control the toggle of showing and hiding the filters